# Vendor Address in Shipment PDF in Magento with Udropship

Tags: magento, pdf

i'm working for customize the Packing Slip / Shipment PDF for the Vendor.

I want to print the Address of the Vendor in the Packing Slip but i don't know how to find this information.

I think the solution can be to use this code:

```
$this->_currentShipment->getUdropshipVendor()->getBillingAddress();
```

but if i try to put this in pdf doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

Mage::helper('udropship')->getVendor($this->_currentShipment-  >getUdropshipVendor())->getFormatedAddress('pdf')

in
app\code\community\Unirgy\Dropship\Model\Pdf\Shipment.php